# Get currently invisible text from multiline textview android

Tags: android

I have a multi-line textview.Its height is depend on other view.I want to get the invisible text from the textview.

I have tried this code to get the invisible text but its showing only empty text but the textview have invisible text

```
final TextView shortDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.short_description);
    shortDescription.setText(data.getDescription());

    ViewTreeObserver vto = shortDescription.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            String text = list.get(position).getDescription();
            Layout layout = shortDescription.getLayout();
            int end = layout.getLineEnd(layout.getLineCount() - 1);
            String invisibletext = text.substring(end, text.length());
            Log.e("TAG", "Invisible text:" + invisibletext);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should be more clear on the "it's not working".

Comment: its showing only empty text but the textview have invisible text